# Python Loop Code

Tags: python, loops, nested

I'm trying to get Python to do a nested loop to print out like this:

```
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Without using the `print("10 11 12 13 14")` function, but rather the:

```
for I in range (10)
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the asked results:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(' '.join(str(j) for j in range(10, 20)))
```

But you might want to spend a look in a basic programming book for Python [like this one](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/python/), since the question is a bit too basic...

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3) :
    for j in range(10,20) :
        print j,
    print
```

The first loop is used to repeat the process 3 times. The second loop prints one line. Note that this syntax does not work in python3.